# Assigning Buttons Using Loops

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe

So I'm stuck with trying to develop a calculator to practice my Swing apps. I'm trying to assign each integer button to print their respective integer in the text field.

```
    for (setBAction = 0; setBAction < 10; setBAction++) {

        numButtons[setBAction].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append("" + setBAction);
            }

        });
    }
```

When I press any numButtons[] in my application, it always prints "10".

I know I can just individually map each button, but I feel like there has to be a more efficient method with a simple loop.

What can I do to fix this code and efficiently assign each button to their respective integer using a loop?

EDIT: Thank you "DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better", with a simple private int, the problem was easily solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code's ActionListeners use the current value of the setBAction when the button is pressed, which is 10, since button presses all occur after the creational loop has completed. Instead, consider giving each ActionListener a private field to hold the value

Something like:

```
    for (setBAction = 0; setBAction < numButtons.length; setBAction++) {

        numButtons[setBAction].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private int value = setBAction;  // set on creation

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append("" + value);
            }

        });
    }
```

Other options including getting the button's actionCommand String via `e.getActionCommand()` and extracting the number from that. Also, all Swing components including JButtons have a clientProperty Map that can hold values when and where needed, and you can put values in via:

```
JComponent#putClientProperty(Object key, Object value)
```

and then get them through the mirror method:

```
JComponent#getClientProperty(Object key)
```